# Jquery textarea not returning value to function

Tags: jquery, textarea

There are some references here on StackOverflow like:
 - [textarea doesnt return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776910/textarea-doesnt-return-value)
 - and others ..
but even with those, I still can't get this to work.

I'm just going to unrespectfully drop my code below. sorry bout that.

**Expected behavior:**
Console shoud return the valye of the textarea when something is entered in it.
**Actual behavior:**
Console returns *"(an empty string)"*.
When I just write `msg = "This IS going through";`  instead of the line where I'm trying to get the .val() ... it works perfectly. Function passes that "msg" variable just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>why oh why</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                msg = $(".mymsg").val();
                $('.hitme').on("click", {param1: msg}, sendNotif);

                function sendNotif(event) {
                    msg = event.data.param1;
                    console.log(msg);
                }

            });
        </script>
     </head>
<body>


<textarea class="mymsg" cols="5" rows="10"></textarea>
<span class="hitme">click here</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because when you use the `val` method, value of the textarea is _an empty string_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `msg` is only set once, when the `$(function() { … })` page load handler fires. That line is not executed ever again. Change your code to say:

```
$('.hitme').on("click", {param1: $(".mymsg").val()}, sendNotif);
```

Comment: thanks ! spot on like the two other answers.

Comment: I called 'success' too early it seems. My testpage just stopped working (no idea how that is possible).
Check this if you want : http://jsfiddle.net/aNysU/1/

Comment: Ahh I see why - from http://api.jquery.com/bind/: "…the variable is passed in by value through eventData, which fixes the value at the time the event is bound.". In other words you can't dynamically set the data you send to an event. You should do something like `$('.hitme').on("click", function() { sendNotif($('.mymsg').val(); });`

Comment: I cannot thank  you enough. Oh wait , yes I can ... accepted answer once more ! :) (thanks)

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the value onload, so the `var msg` will be empty, you need to grab it when you click the event, not when you load the page

Comment: you are spot on. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the value of mymsg when an event is triggered. I would do it something like this:

```
$(".hitme").click(function() {
  console.log( $(".mymsg").val() );
});
```

Comment: I got some very weird behavior with this. This sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't (ff an chrome).
check this : http://jsfiddle.net/aNysU/1    > returns nothing here